# Is there a way to lock table name case in sequelize.js migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, case-sensitive

I was moving a project from windows machine to linux machine and I noticed that names of the tables created by Sequelize migrations are named differently between machines. When created by following script:

```
migration.createTable("Interests", {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  }
}).done(done);
```

On Windows table is named `interests` all lowercase but on Linux it is `Interests` with first letter capitalized.

It there any way to make these work consistently on all platforms?

Comment: Give the table name in lower case to `createTable` :)? This is an implementation detail in mysql, not something caused by sequelize https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Comment: Same thing here. I use AWS DynamoDB as my DB server and Windows machine for local development. And if your table name consists of multiple words (`UserAccountStatus`), they all are lowercase in Windows (`useraccountstatus`), and capitalized in AWS RDS for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your model and pass a parameter `underscored` and set it to true.
This will force your table to have lowercase letters in both windows and Linux. Do this for all models.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Payment extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      models.Payment.belongsTo(models.Booking, {
        foreignKey: 'booking_id',
      });
    }
  }
  Payment.init({
    amount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    booking_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    date: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Payment',
    timestamps: false,
    name: {
      singular: 'payment',
      plural: 'payments'
    },
    underscored: true
  });
  return Payment;
};
```

Also if you use Sequelize-cli to generate migration file, change the table name in create table to an underscored format. It will make it consistent over all the platforms

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('expense_categories', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('expense_categories');
  }
};
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when created using sequelize-cli to create migration and model

Comment: I use sequelize-cli too, I have edited the solution check if migration file changes help. @myselfmiqdad